# Алгоритмы нахождения кратчайшего пути

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Возник такой вопрос, есть ли какие то более менее быстрые алгоритмы кроме алгоритма Дейкстры по нахождению оптимального пути между нодами графа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [табличка из википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Algorithms) для сравнения асимптотической сложности алгоритмов по нахождению оптимального пути между двумя нодами графа:

## Undirected graphs

```
Weights    Time complexity          Author
^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ℝ+         O(V^2)                   Dijkstra 1959
ℝ+         O((E + V) log V)         Johnson 1977 (binary heap)
ℝ+         O(E + V log V)           Fredman & Tarjan 1984 (Fibonacci heap)
ℕ          O(E)                     Thorup 1999 (requires constant-time multiplication).
```

PS в той же статье википедии есть подобная [таблица для направленных ациклических графов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Directed_acyclic_graphs_(DAGs))